# pointer in function don't return correct address

Tags: c, malloc

I try to make a function that allocates an array in C 
and I don't get the right address.

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void allocate_array(int* arr, int size);
void print_array(int* arr, int size);


void main(){
    int size;
    int* arr;

    printf("Please enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    allocate_array(arr, size);
    print_array(arr, size);
}


void allocate_array(int* arr, int size){
    int i;

    arr = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("arr[%d] = ",i);
        scanf("%d", arr+i);
    }
}


void print_array(int* arr, int size){
    int i;

    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, *(arr+i));
    }
}
```

and this is the output that I get:

```
Please enter array size: 4
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
arr[3] = 4

arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 0
arr[2] = 155039806
arr[3] = 32765
```

I tried to print the pointer in "allocate_array" function 
and in the "main" but I get different result.

Please help :)

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you should pass a pointer to pointer into `allocate_array`.

Comment: Or you could make `allocate_array` return a pointer to the first element of the allocated array.

Comment: @ForceBru - I want to avoid pointer to pointer :/ thanks.

Comment: @IanAbbott - I tried buy it didn't work  for me :/

Comment: If you want to avoid pointer to pointer, go with the proposal by @IanAbbott. Return single pointer and assign to arr `allocate_array(arr, size);` -> `arr = allocate_array(size);`