# C unable to read from array of strings out of function

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dirent.h

I wrote a function that scans a directory and copies all file names in it to a `char**` that I pass as a parameter, I'm using `dirent.h` to get the files in the directory, here is my main & the function:

```
int main(void)
{
    char** files = 0;
    int size = 0, i = 0;

    size = scanDir(files, "C:\\Users\\user\\test");

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        puts(files[i]);
        free(files[i]);
    }

    free(files);

    getchar();  
    return 0;
}

int scanDir(char** files, char* path)
{
    int size = 0, i = 0;
    DIR* dp = 0;
    struct dirent* ep = 0;

    files = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    dp = opendir(path);

    if (dp != NULL)
    {
        while (ep = readdir(dp))
        {
            files = realloc(files, sizeof(char*) * ++size);
            files[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(ep->d_name) + 1));
            strcpy(files[i], ep->d_name);
            i++;
        }
        (void)closedir(dp);
    }

    return size;
}
```

I'm using visual studio and during debugging `files[i]` within `scanDir` does contain the correct filename in each iteration of the while loop but in the for loop, it crashes and in the variable watch it says the it is "unable to read memory" under `files`

Why is that happening?

Comment: Other instances of basically the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41665166/1848654, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47520127/1848654, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420131/1848654.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files` is passed by value, and so when `scanDir` assigns to it and returns, the change doesn't propagate back to the caller.

I am afraid you need another level of indirection (`char***`).

```
int main(void)
{
    char** files = 0;
    size = scanDir(&files, "C:\\Users\\user\\test");
    ...
}

int scanDir(char*** files, char* path)
{
    ...
    *files = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could change the `scanDir` signature to `return` the newly allocated `char**` pointer along with the size.

Comment: Thanks! I returned a structure containg the array & it's size

Comment: @Daniel.: Oh yeah, good point: I forgot about size. :)